# Spark Hive Insert In Relation to Table Locking

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

just a quick question. I'm trying to execute a Spark program with a version of 1.6.0 that utilizes concurrent loading on a Hive Table. Is using an `insert` statement in the `hiveContext.sql("insert . . .")` a way to go since I want to ensure table locking during the writing process because from what I've seen in the Spark documentation table locking and atomicity are not ensured when using Saving operations with a DataFrame.

> "Save operations can optionally take a **SaveMode**, that
>   specifies how to handle existing data if present. It is important to
>   realize that these save modes do not utilize any locking and are not
>   atomic. Additionally, when performing a Overwrite, the data will be
>   deleted before writing out the new data."

How can I ensure the atomicity or locking of a hive table in spark whenever accessing/inserting a data in the specified hive table?

Any suggestions are plenty helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution depends on what do you need atomic writing for.

One of the simplest possibilities is to use partitioned external table:

1. In spark job you write dataframe not to table, but to HDFS dir.
2. Once write is complete, you add a new partition to table, pointing to the new dir.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your feedback. But how can I make sure that table locking occurs since save modes done by spark does not have any table locking capabilities?

Comment: Adding partition to external table is atomic (there will be no time, when someone is seeing only a part of inserted data)